# GRUB command to select next boot menuentry via command like efibootmgr

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub, uefi

I'm curious about is there grub has command in operator system can do modified *bootmanger / boot sector* once like `efibootmgr -n {the bootnumber}`.

The `efibootmgr -n` command will switch uefi boot sector in next time boot.

What I want is ***switch on dual OS once*** in windows/linux with select via **grub's menuentry number** by command but not in grub menu mode.(Not change the grub default)

So I think can use grub command both in legacy bios/uefi other boot firmware if it's possible.

Comment: There's `grub-reboot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your version of GRUB is modern enough, there should be a `grub-reboot` command that works essentially the same as `efibootmgr -n`.

For the `grub-reboot` command to work, you may need to set `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` in `/etc/default/grub` if it is not already set that way.